# Why is glUseProgram so slow?

Tags: macos, opengl, glsl, shader

I've been writing a video application that can render a video with a number of different overlays to different devices using GLSL on OS X.

Everything worked well when trying it on a relatively new machine (retina MacBook Pro) but I now got an older machine (MacPro 4,1 with Nvidia GT 120) and I'm running into a bottleneck I'm hoping to find a solution for.

My application basically renders textures and simple primitives. I have a few shaders that do different jobs. One for drawing textures, one for drawing a circle, one for drawing bars... I'm basically applying shaders one after the other using `glUseProgram()` as appropriate by rendering into a framebuffer.

Most of the time, the execution is very fast (< 5 milliseconds) for each render pass but sometimes it takes more than 20 ms which is a problem as I'm serving 3-4 devices at a rate of e.g. 24 fps = 41.6667 ms per frame.

I found that the problem is a call to glUseProgram directly after setting a context as the current one. Here's the code:

```
CGLSetCurrentContext(device.renderingContext);
CGLLockContext(device.renderingContext);
// Setting and locking the context sometimes causes an inevitable GL error.
// We must clear the error here to enable proper error checking below.
glGetError();

[device bindFramebuffer];
GetError();

glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glViewport(0.0f, 0.0f, deviceSize.width, deviceSize.height);

glUseProgram(self.texApplyShader.program);
GetError();
```

Can anyone tell me what this could be caused by and why it only happens sporadically? Does my drawing approach make sense or would it be better to have one shader to do it all?

**Edit:**
I've just been talking to some OpenGL guys on freenode IRC and they told me that it is likely that the glUseProgram call itself. They indeed are right. The OpenGL pipeline seems to wait before it switches the shader. I put a `glFinish()` call before the `glUseProgram()` and now the `glFinish()` takes all the time. I will look further to find the performance leak.

Comment: How have you identified the timings? In general, OpenGL works asynchronous to the application, so one cannot really identify how long each command takes. It could be that several other commands have to be executed before `glUseProgram`. Assuming that `GetError` calls `glGetError`, this is definitely a performance problem since all glGet* commands flush the pipeline.

Comment: On the other hand: on any modern GPU, changing shader program is the second most expensive state change you can do (the first being changing the target framebuffer). See [slide 48](http://www.slideshare.net/CassEveritt/beyond-porting) of this NVIDIA presentation (absolute numbers don't really matter, the shape of that graph does).

Comment: @BDL: Timer queries allow you to time how long a command takes, but they also allow you to infer things that are not true. For example, a GL implementation might defer blocking for VSYNC not when the buffer swap happens, but when the first command that modifies the backbuffer is issued. You might then falsely believe that the command itself is unusually slow and something to be avoided... I'd go on to say that GL's *implicitly synchronous* behavior is the problem. The driver will block some commands at some point for reasons known only to it.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the glUseProgram call itself didn't take so long but that it was waiting for a preceding glReadPixels operation to finish.

Due to your hints, I could further increase performance by removing glGetError and a glClear call. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing a far fetch educated guess here: Do you – by any chance – change any uniform value or attribute bindings in combination with that shader? NV GT120 is quite an old GPU and I'd not be surprised if the drivers on that machine are about as old. And here's the rub: In certain circumstances shaders are recompiled in-situ (even in modern drivers). The old NVidia drivers were particularly prone to shader recompilation if something as simple as a uniform value change happened. Maybe that's what causing the hiccups for you.

Comment: Unfortunalely macOS doesn't expose `GL_KHR_debug`, but on other OSes the NVIDIA driver tells you about this happening via a low-priority debug message.